# Ruby on Rails - Different forms in new actions

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, simple-form

In my form I have **2 radio buttons**. One says **4 users** and other one **8 users**.

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :my_colleagues, [[4, '4 users'] ,[8, '8 users']], :first, :last
```

What I want is to show user different form partial based on what they choose in radio button `:my_colleagues`

My question is can I have 2 different form partial for a new action and how to redirect them to each form based on radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using **jQuery**, you may try the following:

```
count = 4; //This value is based on the respective option selected

jQuery("selected_radio_button_id").change(function(){
  while(count > 0) {
    jQuery(".form-group").append("<label> Full Name </label>");
    jQuery(".form-group").append("<input type='text' name=full_name[] class='form-control'></input>");
    count --;
  }
});
```

Here, `params[:full_name]` will give you the array of user full names.

Comment: Tnx @Abhi , Instead of append (since nested forms will not allow it), How can make it so it clicks on add new button 4 or 8 times?

Comment: @Rubioli That won't be a good practice to click a button 4 times or 8 times. Instead try looping the code that gets executed that many no. of times.